# google app maker - Fill text box based on drop down box selection

Tags: google-app-maker

I am building a google app via the google app maker and have a drop down box with a list of values. What I want is a value to be displayed in a text box based on the value selected in the drop down.

So if you select "X" from the drop down "Y" appears in the textbox
If you select "A" in the drop down "B" appears in the textbox etc

I am very, very new to app maker - all my coding knowledge is in VBASIC.

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to achieve the desired result, but basically you need to start with setting both `names` and `options` for you dropdown:

[image: Bindings]

Once you have that I would recommend to bind dropdown's value to something real, like datasource's filter (`@datasources.Orders.query.filters.Type._equals`) or to particular record's field (`@datasource.item.SomeCoolField`).

In case you are just learning App Maker and trying to do different things, you can bind both dropdown's and textbox's values to page's [Custom Property](https://developers.google.com/appmaker/ui/binding#custom_properties).